# C89 in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, c89

Is there a way to configure the default C/CPP compiler from Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 to compile in the C89 standard?

I am testing code that will be used on a Microchip PIC32 and I would like to make sure they are compatable. It uses C89.

If impossible, what would be a good alternative compiler + IDE combination that supports C89 on a Windows 7 x64 PC?

Comment: Isn't that all you're going to get, anyway? It's not as if Visual Studio supports C99 ...

Comment: Please check this link if you will find any information that might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308944/how-to-simulate-c99-in-visual-studio-for-variables-declaration

Comment: You can use the /Za compile option to enforce strict ANSI C89 conformance, it disables all extensions.  Project + Properties, C/C++, Language, Disable Language Extensions setting.  Click around some more, this is supposed to be discoverable.