# Why does msvc throw C2143 error

Tags: c, visual-studio

This code throws C2143 on vs2008 amd64 (python 2.7 compiler)

(4) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'

```
int f(double B)
{
    B = B;
    double largest;
    return B;
}
```

This change removes the error:

```
int f(double B)
{
    double largest;
    B = B;        
    return B;
}
```

Can anyone explain the issue? I must be going crazy.

```
cl.exe /c test_p.c
```

Answer (score 2):

In some versions of C, you must declare all variables at the beginning of the function, which is why the first example generates an error and the second one doesn't.

Comment: And specifically, older versions of MSVC do not allow declarations after statements.  MSVC 2008 did not.  Note that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25318779/15168) to a question says VS 2013 does support C99-style declarations after statements.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, strange that the error message is so esoteric for such a common error...